# Split with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

How can i split string with char that is not part of the in parenthesis string

Exemple :

`"(ab);(cd)"` split with (;)  ==> `(ab)` and `(cd)`

`"(ab;cd);(abcd)"` split with (;) ==> `(ab;cd)` and `(abcd)`

I can't find the regular expression solution for this 
thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Regex.Split(s, @"(;(?!(\w*\))))")
```

Answer (score 1):

`@"(?<=\));(?=\()"` also works:

```
string str = "(ab;cd);(abcd)";

string[] arr = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=\));(?=\()");

foreach (string str in arr)
    Console.WriteLine(str); 

// (ab;cd)
// (abcd)
```